# Android obfuscation hide salt value

Tags: android, obfuscation, salt

When following the [Application Licensing](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html) document on the developer page for Android to use ServerManagedPolicy for licensing, then the section [Implementing an Obfuscator](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html#impl-Obfuscator) says to declare a private static final array of 20 with random bytes called SALT. This is passed to the constructor of AESObfuscator and the description says it's "an array of random bytes to use for each (un)obfuscation". I am new to this, but I guess that is for obfuscating preference values.

When later I obfuscate the code itself using the ProGuard option delivered with the Android SDK for Eclipse by exporting the apk I get the final apk. But using a reverse engineer application like apktool on my apk reveals the SALT array in plain bytes. Now, like I said I am new to this and my question might seem a bit naive... but isn't that a bad thing? Shouldn't the byte array be a bit more hidden?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A salt value is not a secret, so it's not really a problem if it is disclosed. That said, the obfuscator mangles *code* (mostly variable and method names), not *values*. So anything you have stored as is (strings, byte arrays, your obfuscation key) will be recoverable by decompilation. 
Obfuscating makes it a bit harder to find, but if you are purposefully looking for a random-looking 16-byte array or a 128-bit key, it not too hard to find.

BTW, that example doesn't really promote best practices -- you should use a randomly generated 
new salt value for every encryption operation, and store it along with the encrypted data. *Not* hard-code it your encryption code and use it every time. Then again, that example assumes you will be encrypting (for obfuscation purposes) a single preference only.

Comment: Thanks. I got the impression by the document, that this would be the simple "ultimate way" of doing this, so I see now that I need to dig much further into this before publishing.